# Sugarcrm and Auth0 SSO enabling

Tags: single-sign-on, sugarcrm, auth0

I have one sugarcrm application and Web application. For user login purpose i am using Auth0 in my web Application. When user logged into my application, the same user want to login in sugarcrm.
Is it possible by using SSO? or do we need to pass the corresponding logged in user details to sugarcrm for login?

Please suggest the better option

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. You need to enable SAML in SugarCRM. In Auth0 you would add SugarCRM as any other app (**Dashboard > Apps/API > NEW**), then configure it for SAML (**Addons > SAML**).

The parameters in Auth0's SAML config are app dependent (whatever SugarCRM expects). The most important parameters are:

1. The "ACS". This is the URL where the SAML Response is sent to (this is a location in Sugar)
2. The signing certificate (you will find this on the **Usage** section of Auth0's SAML config). This is the certificate the SAMLResponse is signed with.

Comment: How can we get the logged in user SugarCRM session id from SSO login?

Comment: After sso in my browser console i am getting the following error "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost/sugarcre/cache/jsLanguage/index.php?action=Login&module=Users"